# GCJ cannot find GCCMain class

Tags: java

I am new to linux and programming in general and I can't even seem to get the simple Hello World code to run. Below is what i have done and the error I am receiving, I am using Cygwin. Can anyone help me?

```
theys@THEYS1 ~/java
$ vim test.java

theys@THEYS1 ~/java
$ ls
helloworld.java  test.java

theys@THEYS1 ~/java
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 THEYS1 1.7.15(0.260/5/3) 2012-05-09 10:25 i686 Cygwin

theys@THEYS1 ~/java
$ cat test.java
public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
            System.out.println ("Hello World!");
    }
}

theys@THEYS1 ~/java
$ gcj --main=test -o test test.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.GCCMain
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.GCCMain    not found in
   gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[], 
     parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader    {urls=[], parent=null}}
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you're on Linux, is there any particular reason to use Cygwin?  You can explicitly install/use openjdk6-jdk, and `javac` to compile your code.

Comment: And is there any particular reason to use `gcj`. It's not a Java compiler, or environment, it is a crippled subset.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically because you class-path is not set properly.. Like Makoto said use openjdk it's much cleaner! Just read this http://sandeepseshan.blogspot.com/2011/06/cygwin-java-and-classpath-problem.html. The link is for windows but its easily and quickly adaptable.

And make sure you set the current folder `.`(which stands for the current directory) there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's an installation problem of GCC, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45433. Either no file name was specified in the `--with-ecj-jar` option when configuring GCC. Or the file name that was specified in the `--with-ecj-jar` option when configuring GCC does not exist on your system, at the same location. You can find this file name hard-coded in ecj1, through a command like this:

`$ strings < /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/ecj1.exe | fgrep java.class.path=`

where the precise location of the ecj1 executable, of course, varies depending on your system.